# IAP - Cannot connect to iTunes Store - only during apple review

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I added in-app-purchase (one non-consumable, "unlock premium" item) to my iOS App, and during testing on iphone8 (dev.prov) with sandbox user, it works nicely.

However, when I send for review (distr prov), they reject it, as purchase fails  with "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". They attached a screenshot.

I set up everything properly (tax/bank info, bundle id, in-app-purchase item, itunesconnect, apple dev site, etc). All apple services status are green. Searching all forums, helps, code, etc in the last days, but I do (as I see) everything as I should.

To tell you, during test, I also had sometimes "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" errors, but usually re-try solved it. This was on 11.0.2. Yesterday I upgraded to phone to 11.2.6 (same as apple reviewers use), since that, I had no even occasionally "Cannot connect to iTunes Store", works like charm. Create new sandbox tester, logout AppleStore on phone, reinstall app, initiate purchase, enter new sandbox tester appleid/pwd, and purchase complete. Repeat with other sandbox email, works. Repeat, works...
Restore purchase - also works.
If I uninstall and purchase again with the same testers, it asks "do you want to get the item for free" - also works as it should.

But for reviewers, it fails.
What else can I do in this case?

**Edit:**
Their message starts: *We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 11.2.6 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.*

I tried doing purchase with "airplane" mode, and I got the same error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store. But I expect testers don't test IAP without internet, that would be stupid, and my error message would be proper that case.

However, I did not test on IPv6 (I don't have), could it be that my App IAP does not work on IPv6, thus behaves like in "airplane" mode?

Comment: I have exactly same issue. Non-consumable, review's comment, screen shot for "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update, after a while, after a few ping-pong with review team, it got accepted, and since that, it works fine (also for review team during app updates).
Probably some internal issues they had.

Answer (score 2):

You should test on IPv6 as well. See the link below on how to set up an IPv6 testing network on your mac. If IAP does work for you on IPv6, I would write the review team and ask them to either try again or provide you with more info on how to reproduce the issue.

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

Also, please note that many developers have been having issues with the sandbox environment lately:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/300072